# search particular pattern file using os.walk or any other module

Tags: python

I need to search file in the directory with particular pattern.it works fine if I know exact file name But I need to search file like slope_1.xlsx or slope_2.xlsx...... till 100.
if I use only slope it does not return any output.
Any input.

```
#! /usr/bin/env py
import os

for root,dir,files in os.walk("."):
    if 'slope.xlsx' in files:
        print files
```

Comment: Try regex ( re ) in python

Comment: it's already existing and tested code. Can we achive similiar thing using os.walk .So I can add one or condition and make sure nothing has broken

Comment: Try this http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.walk` searches into the subdirectories of your top dir, if your data files are all in one folder, just `glob` the filenames:

```
import os, glob
data_path='.'
os.chdir(data_path)
for fname in glob.glob('slope_*.xlsx'):
    print fname
```

Answer (score 1):

Using glob module in python

Eg from python documentation

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('./[0-9].*')
['./1.gif', './2.txt']
>>> glob.glob('*.gif')
['1.gif', 'card.gif']
>>> glob.glob('?.gif')
['1.gif']
```

Comment: Thx Akhil. But it will seach into current working directory. if I want to search in particular location.

Comment: You can try this along with os.walk